# OpenLDAP SSL error

Tags: linux, debian, ssl, openldap, openssl

I did setup an OpenLDAP server with PAM authentication against it.
In clear text, it works very well but when I try to add SSL it always faill.

I'm following that guide to get it working :
http://kidrek.fr/blog/?p=30

I'm doing that on a Debian lenny system.
In my logs I can see :
Sep  9 17:00:48 Hostname slapd[3231]: connection_read(13): checking for input on id=14
Sep  9 17:00:48 Hostname slapd[3231]: connection_read(13): unable to get TLS client DN, error=49 id=14
Sep  9 17:00:48 Hostname slapd[3231]: connection_get(13): got connid=14
Sep  9 17:00:48 Hostname slapd[3231]: connection_read(13): checking for input on id=14
Sep  9 17:00:48 Hostname slapd[3231]: ber_get_next on fd 13 failed errno=0 (Success)
Sep  9 17:00:48 Hostname slapd[3231]: connection_closing: readying conn=14 sd=13 for close
Sep  9 17:00:48 Hostname slapd[3231]: connection_close: conn=14 sd=13

On the client side :
Sep  9 17:00:47 Hostname id: nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server - Server is unavailable
Sep  9 17:00:47 Hostname id: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as cn=admin,dc=company,dc=local - Can't contact LDAP server
Sep  9 17:00:47 Hostname id: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://brublunm13.company.local/: Can't contact LDAP server
Sep  9 17:00:47 Hostname id: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
Sep  9 17:00:47 Hostname id: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as cn=admin,dc=company,dc=local - Can't contact LDAP server
Sep  9 17:00:47 Hostname id: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://brublunm13.company.local/: Can't contact LDAP server
Sep  9 17:00:47 Hostname id: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server (sleeping 1 seconds)...
Sep  9 17:00:48 Hostname id: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as cn=admin,dc=company,dc=local - Can't contact LDAP server
Sep  9 17:00:48 Hostname id: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://brublunm13.company.local/: Can't contact LDAP server
Sep  9 17:00:48 Hostname id: nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server - Server is unavailable

Also, in my slapd.conf I got :
TLSVerifyClient     never

Any idea on this ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to use client-side SSL instead of server-side; the client identifies itself using a certificate rather than a password.

Do note that the OpenLDAP SSL implementation is rather tricky - it took me quite a while to figure out that it reads it's SSL certs AFTER it drops privileges, so the SSL-certs need to have read-permissions for the OpenLDAP-user...

Answer (score 0):

I currently have SSL working with OpenLDAP on RHEL - in my slapd.conf, I have:

```
TLSCACertificateFile /etc/openldap/cacerts/cacert.pem
TLSCertificateFile /etc/openldap/cacerts/slapdcert.pem
TLSCertificateKeyFile /etc/openldap/cacerts/slapdkey.pem
```

You can use:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:636 -showcerts
```

to check that the server cert is installed and working correctly, and

```
ldapsearch -ZZ -x -D 'cn=manager,dc=domain,dc=com' -W 'objectclass=*' -v
```

to check that TLS is working.

I mainly referenced http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/185.html for getting certs generates, and correct permissions set.